# Why isn't my LoRa module working with Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, lora

**Pin connections:**

AI-Thinker LoRa SX1278 A-2 Module | Arduino Uno R3 SMD

3.3V | 3.3V

GND | GND

NSS | D10

DIO0 | D2

SCK | D13

MISO | D12

MOSI | D11

RST | D9

`Region: Pakistan`

**Arduino-LoRa Library by Sandeep Mistry**

**Sender:**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

String InputString;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("LoRa Receiver");
  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }
}
void loop() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    InputString = Serial.readString();
    LoRa.beginPacket();
    LoRa.print(InputString);
    LoRa.endPacket();
    Serial.print("LoRa Send: ");
    Serial.println(InputString);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
LoRa Receiver
Starting LoRa failed!
```

**Note:** All components are new.

[image: Image Of Ardunio]

[image: Image Of SX 1278]

Could it be a region problem or a hardware issue? I have two SX1278 modules, and I've tried running them with the same configuration, but neither seems to work.

Comment: It looks like the headers on your LoRa module are not soldered. The connection is probably flaky, at best. No wonder the library can't initialize the module...

Comment: @dda  Hmm, you are correct. I acknowledge that soldering the headers would provide a more stable connection. However, is it still possible to establish a connection without soldering

Comment: And of course without an antenna, you're going to destroy your LoRa module (while getting no RF in or out).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem with the LoRa module not working with Arduino is a loose connection. Soldering the connections, particularly the header pins, is likely to resolve this issue